# intellij - bind jcombobox to arraylist

Tags: swing, intellij-idea

I am using intellij and I have an arraylist which I want to display its toStirng.
I want to accomplish the following
1. iterate through its value and get the object value,
2. when changed - get the object not only the string

- will I have to mark the custom create in intellij and to create it myself ?
  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using **Custom create** property is the preferred way for such cases.